# Pandas Dataframe: I want to use round() while dividing columns, but I'm getting an error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable rint method

`state_trend['Percent Change'].round(2)`

There's a bunch of floats and ints in that column. Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: state_trend['Percent Change'] = str(round(state_trend['Percent Change'], 2))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is a bit misleading here and actually has nothing to do with the zeros.

The quick answer is:

```
state_trend['Percent Change'].astype(float).round(2)
```

I managed to replicate the error when the series is of type **object**. For float format the round function works well. And in the object format case, you get the same error with or without zeros

So all this code works as expected:

```
import pandas as pd

>>> s1 = pd.Series([0, 1, 2]) / pd.Series([1,2,3])
>>> s2 = pd.Series([1, 1, 2]) / pd.Series([1,2,3])

>>> s1.round(2)
0    0.00
1    0.50
2    0.67
dtype: float64

>>> s2.round(2)
0    1.00
1    0.50
2    0.67
dtype: float64
```

But when you convert the series to object you get the rounding error:

```
>>> t1 = s1.astype(object)
>>> t2 = s2.astype(object)

>>> t1.round(2)
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'rint'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2218, in round
    result = self._values.round(decimals)
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable rint method
```

And this is with and without the zero:

```
>>> t2.round(2)
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'rint'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2218, in round
    result = self._values.round(decimals)
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable rint method
```

So I just converted to float before the rounding:

```
>>> t1.astype(float).round(2)
0    0.00
1    0.50
2    0.67
dtype: float64
>>>
```

A final question will be how did the `state_trend['Percent Change']` become of type `object`... generally this happens if you had None values before or the first series that generated the percent where of type object themselves.